# Guidewire PolicyCenter columns minWidth

Tags: extjs, guidewire

I need to make columns width depended on content. But it's configured somewhere that min columns width should be 180, so there is too much space in cells. I believe this is somewhere in js, but i cant find the exact place.
Also I would like to know how to build this js files, when i make any changes. I discovered guidewire use Ext library, but I'm not really familiar with any js, I just want to change minWidth of my columns.

Comment: Dear Twinko Jek, please update your question with a piece of code. Basically you can either set minWidth, maxWidth, width or flex - but as it looks like Ext is shipped in a framework, it would be good to see the code to give a better answer. Technically you could just overwrite that part and load the js after Guidewire has been loaded.

Comment: @hwsw there is no code, I`m just looking for way how to do it. How do you overwrite this ?

Comment: You have not mentioned the version and toolkit of ExtJs.